# Is there some classification of continuous convex capacities by the extreme points of its core?

Tags: measure-theory, convex-analysis

There are many papers studies the core of capacities. In particular, the core of convex capacities on a measurable space has many characterizations. It is well known that a convex capacities $\mu$ can be written as the minimum of the additive probabilities in its core, denoted by $\mathrm{core}(\mu)$. Since $\mathrm{core}(\mu)$ is a convex compact set (in the weak*-topology), it follows that
$\mu=\min_{P\in \mathrm{ex(core}(\mu))}P$,
where $\mathrm{ex(core}(\mu))$ is the set of extreme points of $\mathrm{core}(\mu)$.
However, I cannot find any paper which characterizes the convex capacity by the extreme points (such as cardinality). Because I don't know much about the results in convex analysis, I am eager to learn about some papers or results about it.

If in addition, $\mu$ is continuous, then we have that each $P\in \mathrm{core}(\mu)$ is a probability. If there exist some results under the assumption $\mu$ is continuous, this is also nice.

Any advices be greatly appreciated.